# Resize image after insert in excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I want to resize image after I insert it on excel sheet. I'm inserting picture like this:

```
Excel.Pictures p = myWorkSheet.Pictures(System.Type.Missing) as Excel.Pictures;
Excel.Picture pic = null;

pic = p.Insert(path + pic_name + ".png", System.Type.Missing);

pic.Left = Convert.ToDouble(picPosition.Left);
pic.Top = picPosition.Top;
```

I've tried to resize the picture before insert but it looses its quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!! I've just put next three lines in code above:

```
pic.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
                        pic.ShapeRange.Width = 170;
                        pic.ShapeRange.Height = 170;
```

So, now it looks like this:

```
Excel.Pictures p = myWorkSheet.Pictures(System.Type.Missing) as Excel.Pictures;
Excel.Picture pic = null;

pic = p.Insert(path + pic_name + ".png", System.Type.Missing);

pic.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
pic.ShapeRange.Width = 170;
pic.ShapeRange.Height = 170;

pic.Left = Convert.ToDouble(picPosition.Left);
pic.Top = picPosition.Top;
```

and it works great.